# Swift: UIVisualEffectView with rounded top edges and colored border

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, mask, uivisualeffectview

I am trying to setup a view with rounded corners but only the top left and right corner and with a colored border. This is my views class:

```
class PullUpOverview: UIVisualEffectView {

override init(effect: UIVisualEffect?) {
    super.init(effect: effect)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                  byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft],
                                  cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).cgPath
    layer.mask = maskLayer

    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.frame = bounds
    borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 1
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

I add the view to my viewController view in the `viewDidLoad` method like this (`overviewRect` is correctly setup):

```
let overview = PullUpOverview(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.extraLight))
overview.frame = overviewRect
self.mapView.addSubview(overview)
```

But if I add the view nothing appears. If I change the `PullUpOverview`'s super class to UIView and change my code in the `viewDidLoad` method to following the view and its mask is added and applied correctly (obviously the blur effect is missing that's why I tried to do the same with and `UIVisualEffectView`):

```
let overview = PullUpOverview(frame: overviewRect)
self.mapView.addSubview(overview)
```

So what do I have to change that I get an UIVisualEffectView with two rounded corners (both top corners) and a border layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size` is `zero` for `bounds` so both layers can not be visible. You can introduce a custom initializer as below,

```
class PullUpOverview: UIVisualEffectView {

    init(effect: UIVisualEffect?, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(effect: effect)

        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                                      byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft],
                                      cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)).cgPath
        maskLayer.frame = rect
        layer.mask = maskLayer

        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.frame = rect
        borderLayer.path = maskLayer.path
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 1
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And now you can initialize and add this `view` as,

```
let overviewRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
let overview = PullUpOverview(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark), size: overviewRect.size)
overview.frame = overviewRect
self.view.addSubview(overview)
```

This will result into following,

[image]